# how can we infer/induce/deduce that ( 2 Corinthians 6:14 ) bible verse's use of "yoked"/ "bound" / "close association" does refer to marriage?

Tags: paul, pauline-epistles, 2-corinthians, marriage

( Related Posting:

[2 Corinthians 6:14 - What does "Unequally Yoked" mean?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/24729/2-corinthians-614-what-does-unequally-yoked-mean)

)

> ( 2 Corinthians 6:14 ) King James Bible
>
> Be ye not unequally yoked
> together with unbelievers: for what fellowship hath righteousness with
> unrighteousness? and what communion hath light with darkness?
>
> ( 2 Corinthians 6:14 ) New King James Version
>
> Do not be unequally
> yoked together with unbelievers. For what fellowship has righteousness
> with lawlessness? And what communion has light with darkness?
>
> ( 2 Corinthians 6:14 ) New American Standard Bible
>
> Do not be
> mismatched with unbelievers; for what do righteousness and lawlessness
> share together, or what does light have in common with darkness?
>
> ( 2 Corinthians 6:14 ) NASB 1995
>
> Do not be bound together with
> unbelievers; for what partnership have righteousness and lawlessness,
> or what fellowship has light with darkness?
>
> ( 2 Corinthians 6:14 ) Weymouth New Testament
>
> Do not come into close
> association with unbelievers, like oxen yoked with asses. For what is
> there in common between righteousness and lawlessness? Or what
> partnership has light with darkness?

There is No contextual aspects around the ( 2 Corinthians 6:14 ) bible verse that Directly indicate that said verse is referring to marriage, however, how can we infer/induce/deduce that ( 2 Corinthians 6:14 ) bible verse does refer to marriage?

Comment: We cannot because it refers mingling and fellowship, company.

Comment: @Michael16 The comments sections dialog between me & Dottard gives some really good arguments so please read the comments section under   https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/76464/19810

Comment: That's obvious that it would include marriage if it forbids even friendship. It is not even a question about it. Marriage is the closest relation. It doesn't forbid employment relation which is professional.

Comment: @Michael16  My argument was that we can definitely infer/deduce/induce that ( 2 Corinthians 6:14 ) refers to all marriages involving a Christian, but all other Nonmarriage relationships need to analyzed on an individual case-by-case basis based on degree of intimacy, seriousness, length, intensity, etc., to determine if  ( 2 Corinthians 6:14 ) refers to said Nonmarriage relationships.

Comment: You should formulate it as Can we infer that it **also applies** to marriage. Your question seems to suggest it *simply* refers to marriage.

Answer (score 6):

The verb in 2 Cor 6:14 is ἑτεροζυγέω (heterozugeó) is a hapex legomenon.  In this verse, according to BDAG, it means:

> draft animals that need different kinds of yokes because they are
> different species [eg, an ox and a donkey] ... generally, "not
> belonging together" ... **be unevenly yoked, be mismatched**, with someone
> ...

Thus, the metaphor of unevenly yoked here is applied, according to the same verse to μετοχή (metoche, another hapex legomenon) = a sharing partnership = a close relation between partners, i.e. people sharing something held in common.  Such a close relationship/partnership might be any of the following:

- marriage
- close, long-term business relationship
- any other such partnership involving a significant amount of shared decisions which necessarily includes the sharing of personal values, morals and ethics.

Therefore, I would not limit this verse to merely marriage, but any other such close relationship as described above.  This is confirmed by the repeated (six-fold) parallel statements that compose 2 Cor 6:14-16 as follows:

- Do not be **unequally yoked** with unbelievers.
- For what **partnership** can righteousness have with wickedness?
- Or what **fellowship** does light have with darkness?
- What **harmony** is there between Christ and Belial?
- Or what does a believer have **in common** with an unbeliever?
- What **agreement** can exist between the temple of God and idols?

Comment: Thanks. But, Would you also agree with my answer post ( https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/76463/19810  ) that states that Marriage is the strongest type of human-to-human relationship that can definitely be associated with terms like "yoked"/ "bound" / "close association"?  (In other words, we can infer/induct/deduce that 2 Corinthians 6:14 can certainly at the very least be referring to marriage because marriage is the most "yoked" / "bounded" / "closely associated" human-to-human relationship in this world.  But, other relationships like manager-employee, etc, are less intimate

Comment: @crazyTech - I fully agree that marriage is the closest hum relationship possible.  That is why the metaphor of "yoked" is so obviously aimed at marriage and others as well.

Comment: In my answer post, I was trying to emphasize that (2 Corinthians 6:14) would certainly at the very least be referring to marriage because that is most "yoked" / "bounded" / "closely associated" human-to-human relationship in this world while the other relationships like manager-employee, business partner-to-business partner, president-to-nation, etc., are relatively less intimate, less serious than marriage therefore depending on how intimate & serious these other relationships are.  A particular formal distant business partner-to-business partner would Not be relevant to (2 Corinthians 6:14)

Comment: In other words,  (2 Corinthians 6:14)  definitely via inference/induction/deduction applies to all marriages that a Christian would be in, but for all other Nonmarriage 
 relationships it really depends on case-by-case as as to whether  (2 Corinthians 6:14) is relevant( thus debatable)  because all other Nonmarriage relationship really vary in terms of how intimate  & serious they are.

Comment: @crazyTech - agreed - I would hate to be accused of suggesting Christian exclusivity (having to completely separate from the world) - even Paul admonished us NOT to do this.

Answer (score 0):

By inference/induction/deduction, we could definitely know that ( 2 Corinthians 6:14 )'s use of "yoked"/ "bound" / "close association" certainly at the very least refers to marriage.
Let's just reason it out:

-If a Christian person has a professional business relationship with a NonChristian, he/she can say that it's debatable if one tries to characterize said relationship with terms like "yoked"/ "bound" / "close association" because it's merely a professional work-related business transaction for making money.

-If a Christan person participates in a team-based sports game(i.e football, basketball, etc.) with NonChristian team members, he/she can say that it's debatable if one tries to characterize said relationship with terms like "yoked"/ "bound" / "close association" because it's merely an event involving jovial/recreational activities.

-However, The strongest type of human-to-human relationship that can definitely be associated with terms like "yoked"/ "bound" / "close association" is marriage.  The reason being is that we can infer/induce/deduce that marriage involves the closest & most intimate human-to-human relationship between a man and woman because they are so "yoked"/"bound" spiritually, mentally, emotionally,etc., to each other.  Furthermore, we can even say that the man and woman become one in marriage based on the following verses by employing "scripture interprets scripture" hermeneutic  which definitely can be characterized as "yoked"/ "bound" / "close association" relationship.

> Genesis 2:24
> New American Standard Bible 1995
>
> 24 For this reason a man shall leave his father and his mother, and be
> joined to his wife; and they shall become one flesh.
>
> Matthew 19:5
> New American Standard Bible 1995
>
> 5 and said, ‘For this reason a man shall leave his father and mother
> and be joined to his wife, and the two shall become one flesh’?
>
> Mark 10:8
> New American Standard Bible 1995
>
> 8 and the two shall become one flesh; so they are no longer two, but
> one flesh.
>
> Ephesians 5:31
> New American Standard Bible 1995
>
> 31 For this reason a man shall leave his father and mother and shall
> be joined to his wife, and the two shall become one flesh.